# Detect span object inside tbody

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

how can I detect a span object inside a tbody that is inside a table?
It works if I remove tbody. I tried everything I could. The object name is `span.description`.

Comment: *I tried everything I could* Show us what you have tried so we can fix your own code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
tbody span.description{Your values}
```

This selects the `tbody` to have the `span` with the class `description` inside of it.

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand what you want. Maybe this?

```
table tbody span {
// style here
}
```

The object name? Do you mean the class or id name?